# Using Wordpress Navigation Menu on non-Wordpress Web App

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to use the main navigation menu from a wordpress page on a non-wordpress page so that the menu can update on the non-wordpress page dynamically.

I want to be able to update the menu on the wordpress backend, and have it automatically update on the non-wordpress page.

What would be a good approach for accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to include WordPress on a page without using a WordPress theme. Add this to the top of your file (and make sure the path to wp-load.php is correct):

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wordpress/wp-load.php');
?>
```

I've done this before when I want to tap into useful WordPress stuff (like a contact form plugin) on a page that isn't on the WordPress part of my website.

Comment: Great. Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction.